# Object is not a function - Trying to migrate to angular 1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello hope you can help me.

I just migrated to angular 1.3 from 1.2 and I got an exception on the angular code that says my controllers are not a function, this is the definition of one which is expected to be a function :

```
angular.module('Tabs', [])
    .directive('managerRegistrationTab', ['Helper', function (Helper) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'tabs/registration-tab-manager.html',
            transclude: false,
            replace: true,
            scope: false,
            controller: function ($scope) {

            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
                scope.currentTab = Helper.getLocation();
            }
        };
    }]);
```

This is were angular stops working, the controllers variable holds my managerRegistrationTab directive for some reason and it tries to execute it

```
if (controllers) { forEach(controllers, function (controller) { controller(); }); controllers = null; }
```

Anything I am doing wrong here? I dont get what is wrong with it.

**Edit :**

Apparently there is something wrong here, any ideas?

```
<div ng-switch="currentTab">
    <!--This will trigger the tab initialization every time currentTab changes-->
    <div class="progressbar">
        <span ng-class="{'current': currentTab == 'Company', 'un-visited': currentTab != 'Company', 'step1 steps': true }">
            <span>1. COMPANY INFO</span>
        </span>
        <span ng-class="{'current': currentTab == 'Staff', 'un-visited': currentTab != 'Staff', 'step2 steps': true }">
            <span>2. STAFF</span>
        </span>
        <span ng-class="{'current': currentTab == 'Credentials', 'un-visited': currentTab != 'Credentials', 'step3 steps': true }">
            <span>3. CREDENTIALS</span>
        </span>
        <span ng-class="{'current': currentTab == 'Insurance', 'un-visited': currentTab != 'Insurance', 'step4 steps': true }">
            <span>4. INSURANCE</span>
        </span>
        <span ng-class="{'current': currentTab == 'Agreement', 'un-visited': currentTab != 'Agreement', 'step5 steps': true }">
            <span>5. AGREEMENTS</span>
        </span>
    </div>

    <global:messenger></global:messenger>

    <company-info-tab ng-switch-when='Company'></company-info-tab>

    <staff-tab ng-switch-when='Staff'></staff-tab>

    <credentials-tab ng-switch-when='Credentials'></credentials-tab>

    <insurance-tab ng-switch-when='Insurance'></insurance-tab>

    <agreement-tab ng-switch-when='Agreement'></agreement-tab>

    <div class="center-block btns-group center">
        <button ng-click="global.next()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-class="{'disabled': global.loading}">{{ global.nextBtnTxt }}</button>
        <button type="button" ng-click="goBack()" class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'disabled': global.loading}">{{ global.backBtnTxt }}</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'disabled': global.loading}" ng-click="global.save()">Save</button>
    </div>

    <generic:modal></generic:modal>

    <blocker:modal></blocker:modal>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems correct to me at first glance. Perhaps the reference is to another controller?

Comment: This is were angular stops working : 
if (controllers) {
                          forEach(controllers, function (controller) {
                              controller();
                          });
                          controllers = null;
                      }

Comment: Where does that occur in your example above?  Can you show the code that is relevant to the error?

Comment: your `controllers` should be an empty object since you don't `require: ` any. Even if it was, it would be an object (or an array of objects), not a function to be invoked

Comment: I also see ngSwitch in that list, do you mean that the objects there were required by something in my code?

Comment: The message went away when I removed the controller definition from my directive : 
  controller: function ($scope) {

            }
that section in particular, but regardless, still I am having problems with ngSwitch, for some reason it also tries to initialize the controller of the ngsitch and fails to do so and throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

remove 
           `restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'tabs/registration-tab-manager.html',
            transclude: false,
            replace: true,
            scope: false,`
from return block.

*either you could written them as functions. *